# How do I get the Ubuntu loginscreen etc back after installing Xubutu-Desktop?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, login-screen, xfce

I wanted to test out XFCE, so I installed Xubuntu-Desktop, but unfortunately, it's changed my logonscreen, and all those other types of pre/post session screens. How do I return them to the Gnome defaults? I can't find any options within Gnome itself, like I could in my brief fling with KDE.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I will post detailed information later. You will have to change multiple things to get them back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the default splash screen. For that you need to type:

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

It should present a list of alternative splash-screens. Select the one your want.

Answer (score 2):

Run this in terminal:

```
dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and say that you want gdm to be default login manager.

Comment: I ran the command and it just returned to the prompt. Nothing happened: the logon screen, the startup and shutdown screens are all still xubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1384363.html